# loop csv column values and concatenate values to new column in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to loop and concatenate csv column values

My input is
[image]

and expected output is
[image]

can somebody help me how to loop the column values to get the expected output and thanks in advance.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to read the CSV file line-by-line, store parsed data in array, and then do some nested loops.

This code will do the job for your example (only works for 3 columns):

```
<?php

$rows = [];

$file = fopen("your-file.csv", "r"); // open your file

while (!feof($file)) { // read file till the end
    $row = fgetcsv($file); // get current row as an array of elements
    if (!empty($row)) { // check that it's not the empty row
        array_push($rows, $row); // store row in array
    }
}

fclose($file);

for ($r1 = 0; $r1 < count($rows); $r1++) {
    for ($r2 = 0; $r2 < count($rows); $r2++) {
        for ($r3 = 0; $r3 < count($rows); $r3++) {
            echo $rows[$r1][0] . '_' . $rows[$r2][1] . '_' . $rows[$r3][2] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty dirty solution, I hope that you can make it cleaner, using recursion, instead of nested loops in case if you need to parse unknown columns count.

If you have another fixed number of columns, just add more nested loops (for `$r4`, `$r5`, and so on).

More info about how to read CSV file in PHP on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp)

Documentation about `join()` function, which is alias of `implode()` function on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

Comment: The above code does the concatenation of each row values. But the output i need is to loop every column value to the all other column values

Comment: @SreedharKurur oops, sorry, will edit my answer shortly

Comment: @SreedharKurur I've updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Mazurok

Comment: @SreedharKurur please, upvote my answer and accept it, if it helped